# Использование библиотеки которая закомпилирована под пре-релиз kotlin

Tags: kotlin

При подключении сторонней библиотеки в kotlin проекте высвечивается `is compiled by a pre-release version of Kotlin and cannot be loaded by this version of the compiler`
Как исправить?

Comment: Писать автору библиотеки.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пре-релизные версии компилятора Kotlin, с одной из которых была собрана библиотека, намеренно записывают в метаинформацию скомпилированных классов флаг, сигнализирующий о пре-релизном статусе.

Это делается в связи с тем, что до стабильного релиза мажорной версии (такой, как 1.3) бинарный интерфейс классов, использующих новые возможности языка, не окончателен, и релизная версия компилятора может впоследствии некорректно прочитать такие классы.

Поэтому не рекомендуется публиковать библиотеки, собранные пре-релизными версиями компилятора, а релизные версии компилятора намеренно выдают ошибку при чтении пре-релизных классов.

Можно заставить компилятор  проигнорировать версию в метаинформации, добавив в его аргументы командной строки флаг `-Xskip-metadata-version-check`. Однако лучшим решением будет не использовать такие библиотеки (как вариант – собрать их самостоятельно стабильной версией компилятора или обратиться к автору библиотеки).